# how to access enums in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am using ajax to post a request to a php script and a enum is returned from the script i.e.

```
success: function(data){
    console.log(data) 
}
```

on the console I see:

```
enum('Engineering','Finance','Economics','Project Management')
```

Now how can I iterate over the value of the enums?

Comment: enum's dont exist in that way in javascript, that appears to be a string that is being returned

Comment: AFAIK this is not JS, there's no enum

Comment: I retrieved this enum, by reading an sql colomn type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you're talking about associative arrays or maps or collections e.g.

```
var x = new Array();
x['test'] = 1;
x['something'] = 2;
x['something_else'] = 3;
```

you can loop on them via:

```
for(i in x){
   alert( " key: "+i+" / value: "+x[i]);
}
```

But i don't think there are enumerators in JS in general.

**Update as per your comment below:**

** Caution if you're not 100000000% sure of what's coming from the db (the content of str) do not use eval, it's dangerous and it's a gate for XSS.

You can use:

```
str // is the string you retrieved from SQL.
eval(str.replace("enum","var enum=new Array"));
```

then iterate through the array called enum

```
   for( i in enum){

   }
```

Comment: I retrieved this enum, by reading an sql colomn type. So how can I retreive info using js. Some string manipulation functions I suppose?

Answer (score 0):

Enum doesn't exist in javascript, that is being serialized into a string and it happens to bring the type of the variable from php.

You need to change the return type of your php script